# jsp web application relative path

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, relative-path

I want to open a file in Java Class in an AWS Java Web project via Eclipse.

I have my file in a folder called "res" in

I tried this

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("res\\txtFile.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

but not working!

I got

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\txtFile.txt (The system
>   cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Can you show your project directory structure?

Comment: you should be more specific. "not working" can be anything.

Comment: @kukudas FileNotFoundException

Comment: @adarshr

The default structure >
WebContent
src
build
and I added res.
src

Comment: The java class that contains this code at src\package1\candidateKP.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it !!

used this code to get the absolute path of project anywhere

```
  String AbsolutePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
```

then add the relative path you need.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is inside the weapp, you want ServletContext.getResourceAsStream or Class.getResourceAsStream. If it is somewhere else on the filesystem you should probably use an absolute path. A relative path like you used is resolved relative to the directory your appserver started from which might not be what you want.

Comment: it's a java class in a java aws web project.
I can't use ServletContext.

and how can I use Class.getResource() if the file at res/txtFile.txt
and The java class at src/package1/CandidateKP.java

Comment: The path in the war is what matters. If your war has these files at /WEB-INF/classes/res/txtFile.txt and /WEB-INF/classes/package1/CandidateKP.Java you would use `Class.getResourceAsStream("/res/txtFile.txt")`.